# Extracting substring based on the occurrence of a character using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following string.

```
http://localhost:8080/test/tf/junk?tx=abc&xy=12345
```

Now I want to get substring between the third and fourth slash "`/`" using javascript.

To be more clear, I want to extract `test` from the above given string.
Can anybody help me out on this?

Comment: `var index = location.pathname.indexOf("/"); location.pathname.substring(0, index)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your string into an array

```js
var str = "http://localhost:8080/test/tf/junk?tx=abc&xy=12345";
str = str.replace("http://", "");
var array = str.split("/");
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  alert(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Plus One for quick response.